# VB macro in Word to phone home

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, ms-word

I am looking for a VB Script that will "phone home" if the document is open. I have created an empty macro named `AutoOpen` which executes properly when the document is open.

I would like to collect the time, current user logged in, and computer name and then automatically send an email address with that information. Basically to see who is opening that document.

Is there a way to do that with VB in word?

I haven't seen any php like function calls that send an email out for example mail("blahblah@mail.com", "mysubject", "my text"); That is kind of what I am looking for but in VB

Comment: How does someone with 1000 points ask such a bad question XD

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is quite a simple task but we are not a code sweatshop, we are a learning repository, we can help you fix your attempt at coding it. Start by researching "VBA Send email" it's going to give you 90% of the code straight from Google.

Comment: I've opened up word, went to macros, edited a new macro called 'AutoOpen' and then first did a simple message box to make sure it popped up every time I opened the document. That worked.

Next for the sending of the mail I tried 'System.Net.Mail' but it cannot find the library .Net (after System)

Comment: I've searched "Sending email from Word document VB" but there are no good links

Comment: Seen [this one](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/cdo.htm)? (haven't tried, but looks promising)

Comment: Mat's Mug, thank you, that one helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my email code that I use ALL the time.

```
Sub EmailCopy()
Dim oApp, oMail As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(0)
    With oMail
        .To = "Someone@Somewhere.com.au"
        .Subject = "My Subject Title"
        .Body = "Here is the information you asked for"
        .Send
    End With
    Set oMail = Nothing
    Set oApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Try to implement it into your code and post back if you get stuck. You will need a reference to outlook (I am assuming you are sending via outlook? if not you need to use the CDO method posted by Mat's Mug)

Also maybe remove the vbscript tag from your question, this is VBA :)

Comment: Thanks Dan. My goal was have it email automatically and not launch outlook.